# Is it possible to use empathy in new facebook video chat?

Tags: 12.04, empathy, facebook

Now, the facebook doesn't requires to install any plug-in to do video calls. So, with this new functionality, is it possible to use the video call with a facebook account in Empathy now?

Comment: No, and sice Empathy uses the Facebook XMPP server and this will be shutted down in a couple of weeks things seem a little dark.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

Comment: The comment by @xangua already answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614050/is-it-possible-to-use-empathy-in-new-facebook-video-chat#comment864850_614050) by [xangua](https://askubuntu.com/users/9868/xangua)

> No, and sice Empathy uses the Facebook XMPP server and this will be shutted down in a couple of weeks things seem a little dark